Tissue addon. Realizing Tessellations as own separated mesh-objects
i am trying to separate the recorded Tessellations as own mesh-objects out of the a Main-tesselation (made by the tissue addon).
for achieving this i have the feeling of doing a quite complicated work around:

create tesselation with tissue addon

export tessellation as fbx

import to a new blenderfile having blenderBIM addon

separating the tesselations via sverchok / ifcsverchok


i was just wondering if there is a more straight forward way to do this separation?
may be just by python code, geometry nodes or whatever, without doing steps 02,03,04.
would be quite thankful for any advice/idea ...
thx!



